# Reshaping 2D data for Convolution Neural Network (Keras)

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, reshape

I have a dataset that is N_Samples by N_features [N_samples, N_features] and a corresponding labelset that is [N_samples, N_labels]
I want to use Conv1D or Conv2D from keras but I don't know how to reshape the data to fit it

The dataset is around 100,000 samples with 32 features and label dataset is the same length with 6 label classes (100000, 6)

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(None,N_features,1)))

# (i would add other layers after this but right now I don't have any)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=3)

model.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Conv1D` you just need to add a channel dimension with size 1, that is `X_train.reshape(-1, X.shape[1], 1)`. If you wish to use `Conv2D` you may reshape it as `X_train.reshape(-1, 8, 4, 1)` or in any similar way so that the product of the second and the third dimension would be equal to the number of features.